# Automatically refresh filters

Tags: angularjs

I am using a filter to display the time ago since something was added:

```
angular.module('filters').('fromNow', function () {
    return function (date) {
        return moment(date).fromNow();
    }
});
```

How can I automatically trigger the filter for every minute such that the time ago will get refreshed. Can I e.g. use $timeout inside the filter to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As a matter of fact, your feature has actually already been pretty closely described on Angular Docs.

For these kind of things you'd want to use the directives. You might choose to keep your filtering logic inside you filter function or you may place the whole "time ago" logic inside the directive. Whichever way you want.

JS:

```
app.filter('fromNow', function () {
  return function (date) {
    return moment(date).fromNow();
  };
});

app.directive('time', 
  [
    '$timeout',
    '$filter',
    function($timeout, $filter) {

      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var time = attrs.time;
        var intervalLength = 1000 * 10; // 10 seconds
        var filter = $filter('fromNow');

        function updateTime() {
          element.text(filter(time));
        }

        function updateLater() {
          timeoutId = $timeout(function() {
            updateTime();
            updateLater();
          }, intervalLength);
        }

        element.bind('$destroy', function() {
          $timeout.cancel(timeoutId);
        });

        updateTime();
        updateLater();
      };

    }  
  ]
);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">
  Time: <span time="2013-03-23 21:56"></span>
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RfDKxXrTblrKuBiVlddq)

Again, if you take a look at [Directive Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) you'll find that this solution is almost a complete ripoff of a directive example found on that page.

Comment: You can inject the custom filter directly, rather than using $filter, if you want: `app.directive('time', ['$timeout','fromNowFilter', function($timeout, fromNowFilter) {`

Comment: I was aware that you may inject specific filter directly but I didn't know that you have to append 'Filter' to the filter name when injecting. Valuable comment from @MarkRajcok, as always.

Comment: @Stewie How could I get this to work with scope variables? That is I'd like to do <span time="[[variable]]"></span>.

Comment: Well, `<span time="{{variable}}"></span>` or `<span time="variable"></span>`, depending on the way you are reading your attributes from within the directive.