# Angular.js - Apply filter using an interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, time, setinterval

I am using a custom angular.js filter for datetime objects:

```
function relativeTimeFilter()
{
    return function (dateObj) {
        return getRelativeDateTimeString(dateObj);
    };
}

function getRelativeDateTimeString(dt)
{
    if(!dt) return "undefined ago";

    var delta = dt.getSeconds();
    if (delta < 0) return "not yet";
    if (delta < 1 * 60) return delta == 1 ? "one second ago" : delta + " seconds ago";
    if (delta < 2 * 60) return "a minute ago";
    if (delta < 45 * 60) return Math.floor(delta/60) + " minutes ago";
    if (delta < 90 * 60) return "an hour ago";
    if (delta < 24 * (60*60)) return Math.floor(delta/60/60) + " hours ago";
    if (delta < 48 * (60*60)) return "yesterday";
    if (delta < 30 * (24 * (60*60))) return Math.floor(delta/60/60/24) + " days ago";
    if (delta < 12 * (30 * (24 * (60*60))))
    {
        var months = Math.floor(delta/60/60/24/30);
        return (months <= 1) ? "one month ago" : (months + " months ago");
    }
    else
    {
        var years = Math.floor(delta/60/60/24/365);
        return (years <= 1) ? "one year ago" : (years + " years ago");
    }
}

module.filter("relativetime", relativeTimeFilter);
```

At this point, it is not so important which filter I use (I think). The filter receives a Datetime object. The relative time declaration is only valid one second. Meaning `one second ago` must be updated after a second to `2 seconds ago` and so on.

When I apply the filter, this only happens once. So how do I trigger the filter appliance in a regular interval?

I tried the following:

```
setInterval(function() {$scope.$apply()}, 1000) // placed in controller function
```

...with no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you are going to be able to achieve this with a filter.  The reason `$scope.$apply()` doesn't work is because it is watching for changes on the data.  Since the data didn't actually change, the filter never gets called again.

Instead, you need to adjust the data that is being viewed in your controller.  Use `$timeout` instead of `setInterval` because it is built into the digestion lifecycle.

I'd consider using a directive to do this.

```
app.directive('relativeTime', function($timeout) {

  function update(scope, element) {
    element.text(getRelativeDateTimeString(scope.actualTime));
    $timeout(function() { update(scope, element); }, 1000);
  }

  return {
    scope: {
      actualTime: '=relativeTime'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      update(scope, element);
    }
  };
});
```

So you can use the directive like this:

```
<div relative-time="theDate"></div>
```

Also, I found a flaw in your `getRelativeDateTimeString` function.  You need to base your delta off of the current time.  `getSeconds` just gives you the seconds of the given time:

```
var delta = parseInt(((new Date().getTime()) - dt.getTime()) / 1000);
```

Here is a working [CodePen](http://codepen.io/BrianGenisio/pen/abuol).

Comment: This looks pretty good and seems to be the solution. I also found a similar problem on SO with someone using moment.js. http://stackoverflow.com/q/15589145/785210

Answer (score 2):

Below is the working jsfiddle uses directive to update the time, I think you are looking for similar code..

http://jsfiddle.net/vishalvasani/xRg3j/

it uses

```
$timeout
```