# Remove item based on time counter(expired date) Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of item with date associate with each in (YYYYMMDDhhmmss) format and wanted to have some event attached to each card to find out if item date is expired, if expired the item need to be removed. More like acting as time counted for each item.

What is the best way of doing it ?

jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/jc6nE/2/

Comment: Please read `ng-repeat` documentation on filters https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: We can filter the data while we load the  page, lets say each should need a ticker which will checks the date value so that once the expired time is less than current time then the item should removed by itself rather than any page reload.

Comment: I have updated the demo link
http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/jc6nE/5/  

with a working demo based on what i have seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570121/angular-js-apply-filter-using-an-interval

Only thing is, after the element is removed, still the timeout checking happens.

Please change datetime to get live experience.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement the feature.

Working demo can be find under here

http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/jc6nE/8/

Please change the datetime to see realtime experience.

One question is , is it preferable to spin off different timeout?
If there lot of items, will it create some memory issues?

```
var arrayval= [{
    "title" : "Title 1",
    "expire_date" :  "04/30/2014 10:055 PM"
},{
    "title" : "Title 2",
    "expire_date" : "04/30/2014 09:56 PM"
},{
    "title" : "Title 3",
    "expire_date" : "04/30/2014 09:57 PM"
},{
    "title" : "Title 4",
   "expire_date" : "04/30/2014 09:58 PM"
}];
```

Controller

```
function TodoCtrl($scope, $filter) {

 $scope.sorted = arrayval;
}
```

Directive

```
angular.module('counterApp', []).directive('relativeTime', function($timeout) {

function update(scope, element) {
    var  timeDiff =  moment(scope.actualTime).diff(moment())
    element.find(".item-ticker").html(timeDiff);


   console.log("inside update",scope)
    var timeoutVar = $timeout(function() {
        update(scope, element);
    }, 1000);

    if(timeDiff < 0 ){
        element.remove();
        $timeout.cancel(timeoutVar);
        console.log("ithappened",scope);
    }
}

return {
    scope: {
        actualTime: '=relativeTime'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
        update(scope, element);
    }
};
});
```